# How to solve the cassandra batch write to bring the performance problems

Tags: java, cassandra

when I write to Cassandra in java, my cup usage up to 100%, Specific details are written below:

> 1. I use 5 threads write to Cassandra cluster;
> 2. each thread will establish a connection;
> 3. Write 3000 data in batches at a time, each data is an average of 50KB.

This is the way I write to Cassandra in java：
[batch_insert_statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHt2Y.jpg)

Have you ever met this similar problem?  could you tell me something about it? thanks a lot.

update.
The following is my computer's details:

[cpu-memory-details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5vLn.jpg)

Comment: Can you give specific details about your hardware? Like RAM capacity and the number of CPUs? Also could you update your post by specifying your cassandra.yml configuration file?

Comment: The *best* way to get BATCH to perform?  **DON'T USE IT!!!**  Batch statements in Cassandra are not what they are in the RDBMS world.  If you're batching 3000 rows together for an upsert in single trip, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Really?  Can you tell me something about How do I bulk write data to Cassandra?   thank you very much. @Aaron

Comment: There are tools out there to help with bulk loading data into Cassandra.  Cassandra has its own bulk loading tool (but it's not very intuitive), there's also COPY in cqlsh, as well as Brian Hess' loader (https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to establish a connection for each thread. Initialize the connection once and allow the threads to utilize that. Establishing connection each time is a costly act.

Comment: thank you for your answer.  But I follow what you said, and it doesn't work, even  I reduce batch size.  why is that?